# How to reuse a connection in SSR mode?

Tags: nuxt.js

My NuxtJS app that uses SSR needs to contact a data server requiring authentication. They have a client library (let's call it Client).

Every time a user reloads a page, SSR opens a new connection. I'd like to be able to use a single connection and save the cost of reconnecting & authenticating.

I have written a plugin that creates an instance of the client connector and injects it into the context and app. This works fine for client side but server side, the connector instance gets leaked.

My current solution is to hook up to the `render:renderDone` event and close the connection there. The resource leak is avoided but I still pay the cost of reconnecting and authenticating every time a user asks for a page.

The plugin creates a connection and injects the connector into app:

```js
export default async (context, inject) => {
  const client = <SOME CLIENT LIBRARY>
  await client.login()
  inject('ds', client)
}
```

The middleware copies the connector into the renderer.req:

```js
export default function (context) {
  if (context.req) context.req.$ds = context.app.$ds
}
```

The cleanup hook closes the connection once the page is served.

```js
function render(nuxtConfig) {
  return {
    routeDone(url, result, context) {
      if (context.req.$ds) context.req.$ds.close()
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to be able to inject a single instance of the connector on the server side, while keeping the existing logic on the client side.

I tried creating the connector on the `nuxt:ready` event

```js
  async ready(nuxt) {
    const client = deepstream(process.env.DEEPSTREAM_URL)
    await client.login()
    // What to do with the client?
  },
```

But at the location of the plugin, I don't see anything in the context that I could use. In other words, where could I put the client object in the ready callback, so that it can be retrieved in the plugin and injected into the Vue instance? Or is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ended up injecting the connector in the express server before the nuxtjs middleware. This way it is available on the req object of the context. The plugin can use it when performing SSR otherwise a new connector is created.